# PHP MySQL Left Join more fields

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join

I think that is my last question for today :D

I have the tables restaurant, food and a helper table, which just have the ids of both tables. If I'm doing now this:

```
SELECT * FROM restaurants
LEFT JOIN ResFoodHelper ON restaurants.id = ResFoodHelper.resId
```

The output is now the restaurants with a foodId. But if he finds more than 1 food for the restaurant, then i get for each food, which found, an extra output with the same restaurant.

Now it's like this:

If 1 Entry is available:

```
Restaurant 1 - FoodId 1
Restaurant 2 - FoodId 1
Restaurant 3 - FoodId 2
```

But if more than 1 found:

```
Restaurant 1 - FoodId 1
Restaurant 1 - FoodId 2
Restaurant 1 - FoodId 3
Restaurant 2 - FoodId 1
Restaurant 2 - FoodId 2
...
```

But I want something like this:

```
Restaurant 1 - FoodId 1, FoodId 2, FoodId 3
Restaurant 2 - FoodId 1, FoodId 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haven't tested but try something like this:

```
SELECT restaurants.id, GROUP_CONCAT(ResFoodHelper.id) 
FROM restaurants
LEFT JOIN ResFoodHelper ON restaurants.id = ResFoodHelper.resId
GROUP BY restaurants.id
```

Comment: Works perfectly, thank :D.. But what I have to do to get the text for the food from the food table? I tried to add another Left Join, but there nothing happens...

Answer (score 0):

You need to join your food table as well and then you can use [*GROUP_CONCAT*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) which will give you the comma seperated list of foods per restaurant ,also not sure for the column names so i just put them as example make sure you use right columns in query

```
SELECT r.name,
GROUP_CONCAT(f.name) `foods`
FROM  restaurants r 
LEFT JOIN ResFoodHelper rsf ON r.id = rsf.resId
LEFT JOIN food f ON f.id = rsf.food_id
GROUP BY r.id
```

Be ware of that fact it has a default limit of 1024 characters to concat but it can be increased which is defined in manual